# Openshift remote EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, openshift

I haven't found a way to access @Remote EJBs deployed on an OpenShift JBoss 7 instance from a local client.

Is it even possible to access all needed ports or to wrap the JNDI/RMI connections in HTTP?

greetings Florian

Comment: WildFly will do remote EJB through HTTP UPGRADE (I know this doesn't help you right now).

Comment: did you ever figure out how to access the remote ejbs? please update on any progress

Comment: no unfortunaly the project died before I found a solution

Answer (score 1):

If the remote ejb's run on a port other than http, you would have to use port forwards at the moment.

Comment: Thats the problem... Some of our clients are behind Firewalls blocking other ports

Under JBoss 5 we used the UnifiedInvoker for this - is this also available under JBoss 7?